# Creating a relationship in phpMyAdmin using visual designer results in a blank popup window

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to build relationships between tables using the visual designer. When I try to create a relationship I select the referenced and foreign keys as instructed to but instead of the relationship being created a small popup appears with nothing in it.

I am running the latest (4.0.5) version of phpmyadmin through Xampp over localhost. The same thing happens on Chrome and IE. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem with the same tables, on http://demo.phpmyadmin.net (choose the latest stable version)?

Comment: It happens for me too. I've just updated to 4.1.1 (it didn't work before either) and I'm pretty sure I've done the configuration right. The same thing happens for me on the demo. I'm using Chromium on Manjaro Linux if that might have any influence.